# Why the maximum number of transactions in a block is 221?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, blockchain

I made a private network with only one node in it, then I sent 2000  transactions like so:

```
var amount = 1;
var sender = personal.listAccounts[0]
var receiver = personal.listAccounts[0]
for (i = 0; i < 2000; ++i) {
   eth.sendTransaction({from:sender, to:receiver, value: amount});
}
```

Then, I can see that there are 2000 transactions in the txpool, so I start to mine and this was the result:

```
INFO [10-10|16:12:25] Commit new mining work                   number=2684 txs=221 uncles=0 elapsed=1h10m51.957s
```

Looking at the source code, I have found that in the function `commitTransactions` in [worker.go](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/release/1.6/miner/worker.go#L501):

```
func (env *Work) commitTransactions(mux *event.TypeMux, txs *types.TransactionsByPriceAndNonce, bc *core.BlockChain, coinbase common.Address) {
    fmt.Println("commitTransactions")
    gp := new(core.GasPool).AddGas(env.header.GasLimit)

    var coalescedLogs []*types.Log
    //var i int = 0
    for {
        // Retrieve the next transaction and abort if all done
        tx := txs.Peek()
        //i+=1
        if tx == nil {
            break
        }
```

tx := txs.Peek() returns nil after 221 times, but I don't know why. Would you please help me?

My geth version is

```
v1.6.6-unstable/windows-amd64/go1.9beta2
```

Comment: What is the gas limit for your blocks?

Comment: @jiebang In an unmodified geth each transfer cost 21000 gas. Since you cannot include 222 transactions your gas limit is below 222x21000 = 4662000 gas. If you need to include more transfer you need a higher block gas limit.

Comment: where is the block gas limit setting ?  I cannot find it.

Comment: you can set by creating a genesis file for your node, where max block gas limit can be set.